# download attribute doesn't working on chrome

Tags: php, html

When I add a download attribute in an anchor tag, it doesn't work at all. I've used it to create download link to download image from the website, but it opens the image instead of downloading. (I've tested this in chrome).

I've tried in different ways:
`<a href="admin.jpg" download>Click here to download</a>`
and `<a href="admin.jpg" download="admin.jpg">Click here to download</a>`

Comment: `download` only works over HTTP or HTTPS. It won't work when accessing the file from the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a> download attribute
```

If the HTTP header Content-Disposition is present and gives a different filename than this attribute, the HTTP header has priority over this attribute.

If this attribute is present and Content-Disposition is set to inline, chrome gives priority to Content-Disposition.

Comment: Your last scenario is not what the [docs say](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a). They say that if content-disposition is set to inline, then chrome gives priority to download, not content-disposition. It's FireFox that gives priority to content-disposition.